# understanding percentageOfNodesToScore default behavior

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling

The Kubernetes Scheduler potentialy use a subset of the cluster nodes when trying to schedule a pod, depending on the numbre of nodes in the cluster and the scheduler [Configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/).

I wonder what's the default behavior because the [kube-scheduler-config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-scheduler-config.v1/) API documentation isn't clear:

> **percentageOfNodesToScore** [Required] int32 
> PercentageOfNodesToScore is the percentage of all nodes that once found feasible for running a pod, the scheduler stops its search for more feasible nodes in the cluster. This helps improve scheduler's performance. Scheduler always tries to find at least "minFeasibleNodesToFind" feasible nodes no matter what the value of this flag is. Example: if the cluster size is 500 nodes and the value of this flag is 30, then scheduler stops finding further feasible nodes once it finds 150 feasible ones. When the value is 0, default percentage (5%--50% based on the size of the cluster) of the nodes will be scored.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler default behavior in kubernetes 1.25 is enabled when KubeSchedulerConfiguration [percentageOfNodesToScore](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-scheduler-config.v1/#kubescheduler-config-k8s-io-v1-KubeSchedulerConfiguration) it's set to `0`).

The default behavior is to scan 50% of the nodes, that percentage is reduced by the number of nodes in the cluster divided by 125 (exemple: 2500 nodes/125=20 => 50% - 20 point => scan 30% of the nodes). The minimum of nodes to scan is 5% of the total OR 100 nodes.

To fully understand the scheduler behavior, dive into the Kubernetes source code. The function [numFeasibleNodesToFind](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.25/pkg/scheduler/schedule_one.go#L526) (link to kubernetes 1.25)

```golang
const (
    // SchedulerError is the reason recorded for events when an error occurs during scheduling a pod.
    SchedulerError = "SchedulerError"
    // Percentage of plugin metrics to be sampled.
    pluginMetricsSamplePercent = 10
    // minFeasibleNodesToFind is the minimum number of nodes that would be scored
    // in each scheduling cycle. This is a semi-arbitrary value to ensure that a
    // certain minimum of nodes are checked for feasibility. This in turn helps
    // ensure a minimum level of spreading.
    minFeasibleNodesToFind = 100
    // minFeasibleNodesPercentageToFind is the minimum percentage of nodes that
    // would be scored in each scheduling cycle. This is a semi-arbitrary value
    // to ensure that a certain minimum of nodes are checked for feasibility.
    // This in turn helps ensure a minimum level of spreading.
    minFeasibleNodesPercentageToFind = 5
)

// == trucated == //

// numFeasibleNodesToFind returns the number of feasible nodes that once found, the scheduler stops
// its search for more feasible nodes.
func (sched *Scheduler) numFeasibleNodesToFind(numAllNodes int32) (numNodes int32) {
    if numAllNodes < minFeasibleNodesToFind || sched.percentageOfNodesToScore >= 100 {
        return numAllNodes
    }

    adaptivePercentage := sched.percentageOfNodesToScore
    if adaptivePercentage <= 0 {
        basePercentageOfNodesToScore := int32(50)
        adaptivePercentage = basePercentageOfNodesToScore - numAllNodes/125
        if adaptivePercentage < minFeasibleNodesPercentageToFind {
            adaptivePercentage = minFeasibleNodesPercentageToFind
        }
    }

    numNodes = numAllNodes * adaptivePercentage / 100
    if numNodes < minFeasibleNodesToFind {
        return minFeasibleNodesToFind
    }

    return numNodes
}
```